# Target the second, fourth, sixth and so on of a class div

Tags: css

Hello I want to target the second and fourth and so on of a div that have the same class.

I want to make the "some content" div's that have content class to be red. how I do that? thank you

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Some Content 1</div>
  <div class="description">description</div>
  <p>lorem ipsum betta</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Some Content 2</div>
  <div class="description">description</div>
  <p>lorem ipsum betta</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Some Content 3</div>
  <div class="description">description</div>
  <p>lorem ipsum betta</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Some Content 4</div>
  <div class="description">description</div>
  <p>lorem ipsum betta</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question confused me slightly and I'm unsure whether you want to target every 2nd, 4th, etc `container`s, or the children of `container`s. For the purpose of the below, I'm assuming the former. You can use the `nth-child` selector to achieve this, here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/0s3k3s39/

```
.container:nth-child(even) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As you can see, it selects the even numbered containers only in this case.

Edit - further to OP's comment, try the following:

```
.container > .content:nth-child(even) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Edit 2: if you meant every 2nd containers div.content, try this:

```
.container:nth-child(even) > .content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear, I want to target only div's that have content class but not all of them, just the second div.content, fourth div.content and so on each two.

Comment: @jojo try the above edit